# My list column "Checked out by" never gets a value, why?

Tags: list, library, check-out

Using Sharepoint Online, I've added a column "Checked out by". I've also forced check-out. Regardless of who has checked out (and in) a document and regardless to what major version, I never see a name in that column.

Also - when I or someone else try to open a checked out document, it always says "checked out by another user". This used to say the actual name of the user... not sure if this is related.

Anyone knows how to get a value in that column?

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by creating a new view which was identical to the default one (to which I added the checked out to column). So, not really sure why it works but it does.